# How to get a list recently modified files in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox-api

The question is how to list recently modified files in **Dropbox** account using their API?

**Dropbox** web UI can show a summery of [recently changed files](https://www.dropbox.com/recents), but I couldn't find how to do it in their [API documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation).

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API doesn't currently offer any functionality for events or recents, but I'll be sure to pass this along as a feature request.

The closest alternative is to track activity by staying up to date with /list_folder and /list_folder/continue:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue

Comment: That's a shame!

Answer (score 0):

To Track any modifications in dropbox, webhooks will be the best option.
refer: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks